# Is there a "proper" way to fix alignment of text in a \framebox?

Tags: spacing, boxes, framed

The `\framebox` command aligns its contents vertically centered, but this has a tendency to produce results that are extremely visually displeasing. Case in point:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{relsize}  
% Double box just to make things clearer  
\newcommand{\DoubleBox}[1]{\framebox{\framebox{\textbf{#1}}}}  
\begin{document} \noindent  
\DoubleBox{I think this is visually displeasing} \par\noindent  
\DoubleBox{\raisebox{0pt}[9pt]{I think this is an ugly hack}} \par\noindent  
\DoubleBox{\larger\raisebox{0pt}[9pt]{And said hack doesn't work for larger text}}  
\end{document}
```

> Is there a way to fix this that "just works" so things look right at all sizes?

Comment: What do you mean by "visually displeasing"? Of course a boldface doubly framed text is visually displeasing :), but maybe you mean something else. Did you try `\strut` in the argument of `\DoubleBox`?

Comment: I meant the vertical alignment of the text. It looks to me like the text is placed "too high" in the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of solving the problem (assuming it *is* a problem to begin with).

The first one is to "normalize" the height and depth via `\strut`:

```
\newcommand{\DoubleBox}[1]{\framebox{\framebox{\bfseries\strut#1}}}
```

Alternatively, you might ignore the depth:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % for optional argument to `\smash`
\newcommand{\DoubleBox}[1]{\framebox{\framebox{\smash[b]{\bfseries#1}}}}
```